# How to evaluate the results out of script with type module when using addScriptTag

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, es6-modules

I am trying to use addScriptTag to use some modules on a page.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on("console", (c) => console.log(c.text()));
  page.on("error", (c) => console.error(c.message));
  await page.goto("https://example.com");
  await page.addScriptTag({
    path: resolve(__dirname, "verbs.js"),
    type: "module"
  });
  await browser.close(); // <==== Closes before "verbs.js" finishes doing it thing
})();
```

verbs.js:

```
import nlp from "https://unpkg.com/compromise@13.3.1/builds/compromise.mjs";

const selectors = "p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6";
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll(selectors)];
const pageText = links.map((node) => node.textContent).join("");

const doc = nlp(pageText);

const res = doc
  .verbs()
  .json()
  .map((noun) => noun.text);

export default res; // I need a way of accessing res from node context
```

Also how can I evaluate the result out of a module?

**I guess what I am looking for is a way to get some sort of exported results from the module. like to read it default export.**

Comment: I guess you could add a listener on the page waiting for the contents to be loaded before closing it : `page.on("load", await browser.close } )` instead of `await browser.close()` ?

Comment: That's interesting. Will try this. but still there is the limitation of not being able to evaluate the results from a module script. addScriptTag returns void and there seems to be no obvious way of accessing data from module. e.g. reading default export etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe  you could use [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction)?

At the end of the main script:

```js
(async () => {
  // ...
  await page.exposeFunction('useRes', (res) => {
    // use res
    await browser.close();
  });
  await page.addScriptTag(/* ... */);
})();
```

At the end of `verbs.js`:

```js
// ...
window.useRes(res);
```

Comment: I did do this but I am sure you also agree, it doesn't have elegance to it. I want to scale the solution over 100s of different calculation modules, so it needs to be proper.
Having multiple function files without module and then doing page.evaluate over them is elegant but is missing access to other libraries through import. That's why I am looking at this method

Comment: In the end I found a solution that is scalable via exposeFunction. I think it’s fair for you to take the tick home for this :) thanks

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh can you please give your way. I am having the same problem. My import is not working and script not runnin.